# select all elements inside a p tag except on input element

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div style="height:100px; width:280px; float:left" >

<p style="float:left; padding:5px;" id="optionOne">

<label style="cursor:pointer; width:100px" id="optionLabelOne">Option 1</label>
<span style="color:red; font-size:10px"></span>

<input class="u-3" name="ageGroup" id="ageGroup" style="width:230px;" />
</p>

 </div>
```

I have several such repeating divs. I select

tags inside them like this:

```
$('#optionOne,#optionTwo,#optionThree,#optionFour').on('mouseover',function(){
 $(this).on('mouseover',function(){
  //do something here});
  });
```

Now at some later stage i need to execute a click event on "p" tag excluding the "input" tag that lies within.

When i use the below code, click event fires up on input field as well (obvious)

```
$(this).on('click',function(){
//do something
});
```

So what can be done to select the complete p tag without doing anything to input element within.

I tried this as well:

```
$(this).not('input').on('click',function(){
 //// NOT WORKING
 });
```

Please comment.

Comment: Can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation` method of the `event` object:

```
$('p input').on('click', function(event){
     event.stopPropagation()
})
```

Note that there is no need to bind a handler to `this` object as you have selected all the elements:

```
$('#optionOne,#optionTwo,#optionThree,#optionFour').on('mouseover',function(){
    // 
});
```

You can also add a class to the `p` tag and use class selector:

```
$('p.options').on('mouseover',function(){
    // $(this).foo()
});
```

Comment: i tried this but lost the original functionality of click event on p tag as well. And moreover, i used this because i wanted to do something only on that p element that was clicked...m i wrong?

Comment: @MrinalPurohit You should not mix click and mouseover events, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JhryX/

Comment: yes this worked. Can you help me understand .stopPropagation() method? In jquery documentation it is stated that this method prevents bubbling of DOM tree. What does that exactly mean? and how did it worked after click event was already defined on p tag before?

Comment: @MrinalPurohit Events in DOM bubble to the DOM tree, in fact till the document object, by calling `stopPropagation` event is not bubbled from input to the p tag(_parent_), this way click handler is not executed as the event is not bubbled